# More efficient way to remove last N values fom np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with np.arrays. I am trying to remove the last n elements, where n can be also 1.

```
n=5
corr=np.full(10,10)
```

Usually I use this approach with array slicing:

```
corr=corr[:-n]
```

But I was thinking of using np.delete to increase the performance:

```
np.delete(corr,range(-n,0))
```

But it doesn't work, is there any better solution compare with array slicing?
(method able to deal also with case in which n=0, would be a point of advantage)

Comment: Do you want a `view` or a `copy`?

Comment: np.delete allocates a new array, which is most likely slower than slicing (also you need to provide it positive indices, so range(5, 10) or something)

yeah... np.delete is many orders of magnitude slower than slicing.

Comment: `delete` does not operate in-place.  It returns a new array.

Comment: @hpaulj I need a modifyed array....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is an object with attributes like `shape`, `dtype`, and a data buffer.  A view like `A[:-5]` is another array with its own `shape`, etc, but with a shared data buffer.  It's looking at the same data, but only sees a slice.

`A[:-5].copy()` will appear to be the same, but will have its own data buffer, a copy of selected elements from `A`.

There's no way of changing the size of the data buffer of `A`.

`np.delete` returns a new array with its own data buffer.  It uses various methods depending on the shape and delete pattern.  It all cases it is a copy, and slower than slicing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `corr[0:corr.size-n]`. this is the faster way since it is only a view.
np.delete is a copy of the remainding elements.

```
In [9]: %timeit corr[0:corr.size-5]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.delete(corr,range(corr.size-5,corr.size)) 
10000 loops, best of 3: 145 µs per loop
```