# Python 2.7: Add zeros to the size difference between lists of a multi-value dictionary and sum it

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, sum

I have a multi-valued dictionary and I want to sum whatever the values are there which can be done with

```
for key, value in nai_dictionary.items():
    nai_sum_rate.setdefault('%s' %(key), []).append(np.sum(rate_nai[key], axis=0))
```

for any `nai_sum_rate` dictionary, as suggested in [this webpage](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch01s06.html). However, often times the length of the value lists is not the same.

This is the test data on which I'm testing right now

```
time = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
test_dict['a'] = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]), np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

What I want to do now, is to put a `0` in place of missing values for (in this case) the second array where there is no value against the `time` variable values and add them together.

In my previous testings, before the `nai_sum_rate` was a `list` instead of a `dictionary` I used the answer provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36481099/3212945) to sort out the problem with the reference variable `time`. I've been trying with the dictionary but to no avail.

The expected sum is

```
3, 6, 9, 12, 10, 12
```

Comment: For any new development or learning, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: This particular problem is only available with Python2 since the Fermitools package from the Fermi Science Support Center has yet not been ported to Python3. This is just a small portion of work that is not related to the Fermitools but at the backend, I am working with Fermitools to I cannot change from Python2 to Python3.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself, here is the code  that I came up with

```
for key, value in nai_dictionary.items():
    i=0
    while i < len(rate_nai[key]):
        for key, value in nai_dictionary.items():
            for index, values in enumerate(rate_nai[key]):
                if len(time) < len(values):
                    diff = len(values) - len(time)
                    rate_nai[values] = values[0:np.array(values).size-diff]
                elif len(time) > len(values):
                    diff = len(time) - len(values)
                    rate_nai['%s' %(key)].pop(index)
                    rate_nai.setdefault(
                        '%s' %(key)).append(np.append(np.array(values), np.zeros(diff)))
        i+=1
```

It can tackle the problem with any number of values that have a lesser length than the reference variable `time`.