# find index of a value before the maximum for each column in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe as below.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,0], 'col2': [0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0]})
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     0     0
2     1     1
3     0     2
4     0     3
5     0     0
6     1     0
7     2     0
8     0     0
```

For each column, i want to find the index of value 1 before the maximum of each column. For example, for the first column, the max is 2, the index of value 1 before 2 is 6. for the second column, the max is 3, the index of value 1 before the value 3 is 2.

In summary, I am looking to get [6, 2] as the output for this test DataFrame. Is there a quick way to achieve this?

Comment: Assume there is a col3 where 1 is in index 5, everything else is 0. what do you want to return for col3 in this case? Majority of solutions here return either `NaN` or `0` for this case

Answer (score 5):

Use [**`Series.mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to hide elements that aren't 1, then apply [**`Series.last_valid_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) to each column.

```
m = test.eq(test.max()).cumsum().gt(0) | test.ne(1) 
test.mask(m).apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

Using numpy to vectorize, you can use [**`numpy.cumsum`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [**`argmax`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
idx = ((test.eq(1) & test.eq(test.max()).cumsum().eq(0))
            .values
            .cumsum(axis=0)
            .argmax(axis=0))
idx
# array([6, 2])

pd.Series(idx, index=[*test])

col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think this isn't what OP is asking for. he needs to find the `1` *before* the maximal value.

Comment: @QuangHoang "the index of value 1 before 2 is 6. for the second column, the max is 3, the index of value 1 before the value 3 is 2." the output here is 6 and 2. What am I missing?

Comment: This is coincident, because there are no 1's after the value 3 in `col2`, which is the maximum value of that column. If `test.loc[5,'col2']=1`, your solution would give `col2  5`?

Comment: As I commented in other solutions. Assume there is a col3 where 1 is in index 5, everything else is 0. Yours returns `NaN` same as mine for 1st solution and 0 for 2nd solution :)

Comment: @AndyL. The question is "find index of a value before the maximum for each column in python dataframe", if 1 is the maximum, then the index should be invalid.

Comment: @cs95: ah, it seems to make sense to me. At first, I thought it should return `5` as in @WenYoBen solution. So, returning `NaN` is appropriate in this sense.

Answer (score 4):

Using @cs95 idea of `last_valid_index`:

```
test.apply(lambda x: x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1)[lambda i:i].last_valid_index())
```

Output:

```
col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

Expained:

Using index slicing to cut each column to start to max value, then look for the values that are equal to one and find the index of the last true value.

Or as @QuangHoang suggests:

```
test.apply(lambda x: x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1).cumsum().idxmax())
```

Comment: Or similarly: `test.apply(lambda x: x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1).cumsum().idxmax())`

Comment: Surprisingly, `cumsum` is a tiny bit better.

Comment: Assume there is a col3 where `1` is in index 5, everything else is `0`. This returns `NaN` for 1st solution  and `0` for 2nd solution. My solution is also returns `NaN`

Comment: Ah.. yes, that is an edge case  I need to modify this solution for.

Comment: @AAA Did these solutions help you?  Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) a solution?

Answer (score 4):

#### Overkill with Numpy

```
t = test.to_numpy()
a = t.argmax(0)

i, j = np.where(t == 1)
mask = i <= a[j]
i = i[mask]
j = j[mask]

b = np.empty_like(a)
b.fill(-1)

np.maximum.at(b, j, i)

pd.Series(b, test.columns)

col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `apply`

```
test.apply(lambda s: max(s.index, key=lambda x: (s[x] == 1, s[x] <= s.max(), x)))

col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `cummax`

```
test.eq(1).where(test.cummax().lt(test.max())).iloc[::-1].idxmax()

col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

## Timing

I just wanted to use a new tool and do some bechmarking
[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398618/2336654)

### Results

```
r.to_pandas_dataframe().T

         10        31        100       316       1000      3162      10000
al_0  0.003696  0.003718  0.005512  0.006210  0.010973  0.007764  0.012008
wb_0  0.003348  0.003334  0.003913  0.003935  0.004583  0.004757  0.006096
qh_0  0.002279  0.002265  0.002571  0.002643  0.002927  0.003070  0.003987
sb_0  0.002235  0.002246  0.003072  0.003357  0.004136  0.004083  0.005286
sb_1  0.001771  0.001779  0.002331  0.002353  0.002914  0.002936  0.003619
cs_0  0.005742  0.005751  0.006748  0.006808  0.007845  0.008088  0.009898
cs_1  0.004034  0.004045  0.004871  0.004898  0.005769  0.005997  0.007338
pr_0  0.002484  0.006142  0.027101  0.085944  0.374629  1.292556  6.220875
pr_1  0.003388  0.003414  0.003981  0.004027  0.004658  0.004929  0.006390
pr_2  0.000087  0.000088  0.000089  0.000093  0.000107  0.000145  0.000300

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.subplot()
r.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

### Setup

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
b = BenchmarkBuilder()

def al_0(test): return test.apply(lambda x: x.where(x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1)).drop_duplicates(keep='last').idxmin())
def wb_0(df): return (df.iloc[::-1].cummax().eq(df.max())&df.eq(1).iloc[::-1]).idxmax()
def qh_0(test): return (test.eq(1) & (test.index.values[:,None] < test.idxmax().values)).cumsum().idxmax()
def sb_0(test): return test.apply(lambda x: x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1)[lambda i:i].last_valid_index())
def sb_1(test): return test.apply(lambda x: x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1).cumsum().idxmax())
def cs_0(test): return (lambda m: test.mask(m).apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index))(test.eq(test.max()).cumsum().gt(0) | test.ne(1))
def cs_1(test): return pd.Series((test.eq(1) & test.eq(test.max()).cumsum().eq(0)).values.cumsum(axis=0).argmax(axis=0), test.columns)
def pr_0(test): return test.apply(lambda s: max(s.index, key=lambda x: (s[x] == 1, s[x] <= s.max(), x)))
def pr_1(test): return test.eq(1).where(test.cummax().lt(test.max())).iloc[::-1].idxmax()
def pr_2(test):
    t = test.to_numpy()
    a = t.argmax(0)

    i, j = np.where(t == 1)
    mask = i <= a[j]
    i = i[mask]
    j = j[mask]

    b = np.empty_like(a)
    b.fill(-1)

    np.maximum.at(b, j, i)

    return pd.Series(b, test.columns)

import math

def gen_test(n):
    a = np.random.randint(100, size=(n, int(math.log10(n)) + 1))
    idx = a.argmax(0)
    while (idx == 0).any():
        a = np.random.randint(100, size=(n, int(math.log10(n)) + 1))
        idx = a.argmax(0)        

    for j, i in enumerate(idx):
        a[np.random.randint(i), j] = 1

    return pd.DataFrame(a).add_prefix('col')

@b.add_arguments('DataFrame Size')
def argument_provider():
    for exponent in np.linspace(1, 3, 5):
        size = int(10 ** exponent)
        yield size, gen_test(size)

b.add_functions([al_0, wb_0, qh_0, sb_0, sb_1, cs_0, cs_1, pr_0, pr_1, pr_2])

r = b.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

A little bit logic here

```
(df.iloc[::-1].cummax().eq(df.max())&df.eq(1).iloc[::-1]).idxmax()
Out[187]: 
col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @piRSquared ah ,I really need to try hard find something different method . :-)

Comment: I thought about using the reversing element also.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a mixed `numpy` and `pandas` solution:

```
(test.eq(1) & (test.index.values[:,None] < test.idxmax().values)).cumsum().idxmax()
```

which is a bit faster than the other solutions.

Comment: As I commented in other solutions. For case col3 having only one row is `1`, everything else is `0`. Yours returns 0 for col3. We don't know what OP wants in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dropna` with `where` to drop duplicated `1` keeping the last `1`, and call `idxmin` on it.

```
test.apply(lambda x: x.where(x[:x.idxmax()].eq(1)).drop_duplicates(keep='last').idxmin())

Out[1433]:
col1    6
col2    2
dtype: int64
```